# How to update the attribute while overriding a style defined in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question builds on my previous two questions.

I have a css that must be included (`first_style.css` in the snippet below). I have reduced it to `img { height:auto; }` - this is what must be included. I can add any styles before or after. After the images are loaded, I run a script to update the height of the images - see below.

If I do not include `first_style.css`, everything works fine. However, if I include it, as I have to, I cannot find a way to make my script to work. How can I fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.images div a img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).attr('height', $(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'));
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  height:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/themes/pinboard-child/first_style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div imgheight="300px" class="images">
  <div><a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " /></a> </div>
  <div><a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg "/></a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't understand what you need

Comment: The images must be resized (in this example, to 300px height)

Comment: Probably, I cannot use attributes to override styles. Not sure how to use javascript to override styles.

Comment: You have `height: auto` from `first_style.css` file, and you have attribute `height="300px"` that is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.images div a img').on('load', function() {
    $(this).css('height', $(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'));
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  height:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/themes/pinboard-child/first_style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div imgheight="300" class="images">
  <div><a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " /></a> </div>
  <div><a> <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg "/></a> </div>
</div>
```

Onload event cause that the resizing will be produced when images finish to load, not before.

Comment: When I run your snippet, the images are still full size, not 300px high

Comment: @YuliaV wrong, you'll see the resizing when onload finish. That's the problem with onload event, as I explain in the answer

Comment: I can suggest you to avoid `onload` event, and try with `$(document).ready()` because you are not making calculations and always will be 300px height.

Comment: I will need to know the size of the image to expand my script, do I understand correctly that it is not known during the execution of `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: No, you can't know the size of an image before it loads, but you are writing fixed height (300 pixels), and in this case doesn't matter the size of the image, always will be 300 pixels, so you can use document.ready safely

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle for your question :

https://jsfiddle.net/utrsrb70/

HTML:

```
<div imgheight="300px" class="images">
  <div><a> <img class="myimg" src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " /></a> </div>
  <div><a> <img class="myimg" src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg "/></a> </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

  $('.images img').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));

    $(this).attr('height', $(this).closest('.images').attr('imgheight'));

  })


});
```

CSS:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/themes/pinboard-child/first_style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-height` attribute for this and get that data attribute in your script using `element.data('height');`

here is working example

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.images img').each(function() {
       $(this).attr('height',$('.images').data("height"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-height="300px" class="images">
  <img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg" />
</div>
```